# FocalLoss TypeError: expected CPU (got CUDA)

Tags: python, pytorch

I got this error when training my network. From other posts, I know that I'm supposed to put the tensor on the cuda device, either with .cuda() or .to("cuda:0"). However, the same error keeps appearing when I do this.

```
---> 23         pt = Tensor(logpt.data.exp())
     24 
     25         if self.alpha is not None:

TypeError: expected CPU (got CUDA)
```

I've tried adding .cuda() after line 23, but also after self.alpha = alpha, and a few other places. Am I missing something? Or is it my model code that I should check. Pretty sure the entire model is on cuda. Thanks for any insights.

```
import torch
from torch import nn, Tensor
import torch.nn.functional as F
class FocalLoss(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, gamma=0, alpha=None, size_average=True):
        super(FocalLoss, self).__init__()
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.alpha = alpha.cuda()
        if isinstance(alpha,(float,int)): self.alpha = torch.Tensor([alpha,1-alpha])
        if isinstance(alpha,list): self.alpha = torch.Tensor(alpha)
        self.size_average = size_average

    def forward(self, input, target):
        if input.dim()>2:
            input = input.view(input.size(0),input.size(1),-1)  # N,C,H,W => N,C,H*W
            input = input.transpose(1,2)    # N,C,H*W => N,H*W,C
            input = input.contiguous().view(-1,input.size(2))   # N,H*W,C => N*H*W,C
        target = target.view(-1,1)

        logpt = F.log_softmax(input)
        logpt = logpt.gather(1,target)
        logpt = logpt.view(-1)
        pt = Tensor(logpt.data.exp())

        if self.alpha is not None:
            if self.alpha.type()!=input.data.type():
                self.alpha = self.alpha.type_as(input.data)
            at = self.alpha.gather(0,target.data.view(-1))
            logpt = logpt * Tensor(at)

        loss = -1 * (1-pt)**self.gamma * logpt
        if self.size_average: return loss.mean()
        else: return loss.sum()
```

Comment: where did you get this implementation of focal loss?

Comment: From here: https://github.com/mbsariyildiz/focal-loss.pytorch/blob/master/focalloss.py   open to better, out of the box implementations...

Comment: this is a good place to start: https://paperswithcode.com/paper/focal-loss-for-dense-object-detection